# ActiveRecord .missing - Why doesnt this work?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Working on Rails 6.1

I've got this base class:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
end
```

And these two subclasses representing a face-to-face lesson and it's live transmission:

```
class Live < Post
  belongs_to :in_person_live,
             foreign_key: :live_of_in_person_live_id,
             class_name: 'InPersonLive',
             required: false,
             inverse_of: :online_live,
             touch: true
end

class InPersonLive < Post
  has_one :online_live,
          class_name: 'Live',
          foreign_key: 'live_of_in_person_live_id',
          inverse_of: :in_person_live,
          touch: true
end
```

**I'd like to query for face-to-face lessons without a live transmission.**

I came up with this, which seems to work:

```
InPersonLive.where.not(id: Live.where.not(live_of_in_person_live_id: nil).select(:live_of_in_person_live_id)).count
```

But was wondering why this doesnt work:

```
InPersonLive.where.missing(:online_live).count
```

I'd expect the `.missing` to return the same result but it always returns 0.

The generated SQL is different in both cases but again I don't understand why the result is different, seems to me like they should return the same set.

`InPersonLive.where.not(id: Live.where.not(live_of_in_person_live_id: nil)).count` generates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."type" = $1 AND "posts"."id" NOT IN (SELECT "posts"."live_of_in_person_live_id" FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."type" = $2 AND "posts"."live_of_in_person_live_id" IS NOT NULL)  [["type", "InPersonLive"], ["type", "Live"]]
```

while `InPersonLive.where.missing(:online_live).count` generates:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts" "online_lives_posts" ON "online_lives_posts"."live_of_in_person_live_id" = "posts"."id" AND "online_lives_posts"."type" = $1 WHERE "posts"."type" = $2 AND "posts"."id" IS NULL  [["type", "Live"], ["type", "InPersonLive"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi @dwaynemac.

I wonder if you mapped or queried backward.

Maybe `InPersonLive` `belongs` to `Live` and `Live` `has_one` or `has_many`. Or maybe you should query `Live.where.missing(:in_person_live).count`

So, similarly `Something.where.missing(:thing)` should generate the same query.

Because, if you wanted to test prior to `missing` you would do something along the lines of:

```ruby
Live.left_joins(:in_person_live).where(in_person_live: { id: nil } )
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer already gave you the manual way of doing this, just wanted to add that this actually looks like it might be a bug.  The `AND "posts"."id" IS NULL` should be `AND "online_lives_posts"."id" IS NULL`, ie. the null check should be for the `left outer join`ed relation.

Obviously your associations are quite the mouthful, so not sure what's tripping it up, my first guess would be the STI.